# Is it possible to configure Security so that only Methods and Endpoints are restricted in Access if annotated with @RolesAllowed

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I‘m currently running Spring Boot 2 Server with Spring Security and I need to configure each url in Configuration if it should not be restrict the access. But I think it would be much easier if all Methods and Endpoints are permit all requests and only restrict if a `@RolesAllowed` Annotation is added above. So is there any way to configure Spring Security in this way?

My current Configuration for Authentification:

```
@Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.cors().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(urls).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                    .addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

            http.csrf().disable();
        }
```

Example Authorization:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/all")
    @RolesAllowed(value = Role.ADMIN)
    public final ResponseEntity<?> getAll() {
      ...
}
```

Comment: Just permit all request.

Answer (score 0):

I think `hasRole` in the controller method will help.

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    @PostMapping(value = "/someaction", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<?> someaction() {
        return null;
    }
```

Your security config should be something like this. `addFilterBefore` should be chained earlier.

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

http
    .cors()
    .and()
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
    .addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class) 
    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(urls).permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated();

http.csrf().disable();
}
```

Comment: Yes but Websecurity will still lock it general if the URL not Added in Configuration

Comment: When I leave ```@PreAuthorize``` ```/someaction``` is still locked through SpringSecurity because I said everything which is not specified in Configuration is ```authenticated()```

Comment: And as I believe when I say everything should be ```permitAll()```even the annotated Methods and Endpoints would be accessible without authentication, am I wrong?

Comment: `.anyRequest().authenticated()` will make all the request forbidden without authentication and authorization. `@PreAuthorize` with make sure the role is correct, this is authorization.

Comment: Yes I know but I want to authentification only where authorization is set, that was my Question. Maybe I used authetification and authorization not right, hope you get it now.

Comment: did you do `.anyRequest().authenticated();` in config?

Comment: I added it above, but yes I did.

Answer (score 0):

*"But I think it would be much easier if all Methods and Endpoints are permit all requests and only restrict if a @RolesAllowed Annotation is added"*

Yes you are right, it would be much easier, BUT ALSO, much more UNSAFE.
Spring Security is using the strategy "Security by Design" which means that out of the box everything is as secure as possible.

Then you have to EXPLICITLY mark all methods which can be accessed by anonymous users. Perhaps the other way around had been "easier", but we are dealing with security, so this is MUCH SAFER :-)